# iPhone CGRectMake memory consuption

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks

On iPhone.. Why would code such as this cause memory leak? after 2 minutes the net bytes have doubled.
All I'm doing is moving a ball round the screen with an NSTimer calling the below method.

Any ideas?

```
- (void)nextFrame:(NSNotification *)notification {
    ballInstance.frame = CGRectMake(value, 0,  320, 480);
}
```

---

here is the 'full' code, new project, still behaves the same.  It moves a jpg accross the screen, and as it does memory is massively consumed. If I remove the '++' from 'value' memory is fine. (in otherwords have a static graphic) So.... is the image being cached is the question? 
If so how can i stop it reaching astronomical sizes?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    


    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    NSTimer * nSTimer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: .02
         target: self
       selector: @selector(tick)
       userInfo: nil
        repeats: YES];
    value =0;
}

- (void)tick {
    NSLog(@"tick");
    myOutlet1.frame = CGRectMake(value++, 0,  320, 480);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The posted code has no leak. The problem is elsewhere.

If you know that there's a leak inside of `nextFrame:`, it has to be in `-[Ball setFrame:]` because it is the only message sent in this method.

Comment: But if I remove the line "ballInstance.frame = CGRectMake(value, 0,  320, 480);"
...no leak occurs. And as that line has no further interaction with the rest of my code I presumed the line to be the troublemaker.

Comment: @unknown: As Nikolai said, the leak must be somewhere in the setFrame: method that you're calling, because it certainly isn't in CGRectMake().

Comment: unknown: Remember, property assignments (`ballInstance.frame = …`) are messages. A property assignment and a setter message expression (`[ballInstance setFrame:…]`) are exactly the same thing. You are calling the `setFrame:` method, and if cutting out that message stops the leak, then that method is responsible for the leak.

Answer (score 3):

The leak is not in the code you show, especially if `frame` is a `@synthesized` property. You either need to show more code, or spend some quality time with Instruments to figure out what is being leaked and where it is being allocated.

Answer (score 2):

[According to Apple:](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2009/Sep/msg00278.html)

> This is a bug in iPhone OS 3.0. The allocator for the graphics system
>   is reporting realloc events as malloc events, so ObjectAlloc tallies
>   these as new objects that are almost never being freed. I'm not
>   certain why you might not see it when you add the Leaks tool, but
>   neither tool would show a true leak for this.

Though I'm still none the wiser as to how to remedy it.

Comment: So, basically just ignore it and your fine! Very annoying, wasted most of a day.

Answer (score 1):

I've posted a complete sample application that seems to more or less match your "new project" example above.  Can you take a look at it and see if this gives you any ideas?  I've run it on the simulator and on the device w/ no leak.

http://static.fatmixx.com/MemTestApp.zip

It really does look like there is NO leak here.  I'm building against iPhoneOS 3.1 - Debug.

Sujal